# Attempting to plot simulated data in R ggplot yields a strange grey block on left side of plot, what do I do?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to simulate some data for the statistics for my thesis and I feel like I did an okay job doing that, I'm not that experienced with R so it's probably way longer than necessary. I'm trying to plot this data in a scatterplot but it's seriously struggling with it, I don't really know how to explain it but there's this huge grey block to the left of the plot and the data isn't going in order (105 days => 14 days => 21 days). Base R handles it fine but ggplot is just going nuts. What do I do?

Strange things showing up and highest x value is the first followed by the lowest :
[image]

```
dualex <- cbind.data.frame(
      rbind(cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 20, sd = 2), 4), rep('C', 182)),
      cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 19.8, sd = 2),4), rep('T1',182)),
      cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 18.5, sd = 2),4), rep('T2',182)),
      cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 18, sd = 2),4), rep('T3', 182)),
      cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 17.4, sd = 2),4), rep('T4', 182))),
      rbind(cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.35, sd = 0.02),4), rep('C', 182)),
      cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.34, sd = 0.02),4), rep('T1',182)),
      cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.32, sd = 0.02),4), rep('T2',182)),
      cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.28, sd = 0.02),4), rep('T3',182)),
      cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
            round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.23, sd = 0.02),4), rep('T4',182))),
      rbind(cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
                  round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.085, sd = 0.004),4), rep('C', 182)),
            cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
                  round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.083, sd = 0.004),4), rep('T1',182)),
            cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
                  round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.078, sd = 0.004),4), rep('T2',182)),
            cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
                  round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.28, sd = 0.02),4), rep('T3',182)),
            cbind(rep(c(14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98,105), each = 13),
                  round(rnorm(n = 182, mean = 0.070, sd = 0.004),4), rep('T4',182))))

dualex[,c(3,4,6,7)] <- NULL
colnames(dualex) <- c('Day', 'Chl', 'Flav', 'Anth', 'Treatment')
  
#ggplot going crazy
ggplot(data = dualex, mapping = aes(x = Day, y = Chl)) + geom_point()

#base R takes it fine
plot(dualex$Day, dualex$Chl)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, your issue are the factor variables:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
dualex %>% mutate(across(Chl:Anth,~as.numeric(as.character(.)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Day, y = Chl)) + geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]